# Read .tar.gz file in R

Tags: r

I have compressed file like  cat.txt.tar.gz, I just need to load into R and process as follows

> zip <-("cat.txt.tar.gz")
>
> data <- read.delim(file=(untar(zip,"cat.txt")),sep="\t")

but "data" is empty while running the code.Is there any way to read a file from .tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your file is named correctly?
Usually compressed files are named `cat.tar.gz`, excluding the `.txt`.

Second, try the following code:

```
tarfile <- "cat.txt.tar.gz" # Or "cat.tar.gz" if that is right
data <- read.delim(file = untar(tarfile,compressed="gzip"),sep="\t")
```

If this doesn't work, you might need to extract the file first, and then read the extracted file.

Comment: yeah it is not working, got an error like this "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection"

Answer (score 1):

To read in a particular csv or txt within a gz archive without having to UNZIP it first one can use `library(archive)` :

```
library(archive)
library(readr)
read_csv(archive_read("cat.txt.tar.gz", file = 1), col_types = cols(), sep="\t")
```

should work.